# Managing sessions for sub domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 ASP.Net Core 1.1 Apps. App1 is hosted in IIS as a website node. App2 is hosted under App1 as a virtual application.

Each app has it's own session, created in each one's startup.cs. The problem seems to be that App1 removes App2's session.

So, here's the scenario: I browse App2 (virtual app). Then I browse App1. When I go back to App2 the session has been lost or removed.

To be honest, I'm not really sure what's going on - and this seems very unexpected behaviour. Any ideas or help would be very welcome.

**App1:**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.CookieName = ".App1";
    });
}
```

**App2:**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.CookieName = ".App2";
    });
}
```

**Extra info:**
I have just noticed that the cookie that gets created by both apps is named ".AspNetCore.Session", which I believe is the default name. However, as clearly demonstrated above in the code snippets, I am explicitly naming each session cookie differently.

So I guess the real question here is why my apps are not creating their own explicitly named cookie.

**UPDATE:**
I think I have just answered my own question.

Further down the startup.cs page in the Configure method, there was this:

```
 app.UseSession(new SessionOptions()
 {
     CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
     CookieHttpOnly = true,
     CookieName = ".App2" //added this
 });
```

If you click into it, I found there were options for CookieName. It seems odd that you can specify it in 2 places. But anyway, it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems odd that you can specify it in 2 places.

You can configure the session options in two places: Either using `services.AddSession(configureAction)` or when you add the middleware using `app.UseSessions(sessionOptions)`.

If you decide to use `app.UseSessions` while passing a `SessionOptions` object, then the configuration you made with `AddSession` will not apply. So you are effectively overwriting the configured session options.

You can make the configured session options apply by just calling `app.UseSessions()` without passing an explicit `SessionOptions` object:

```
services.AddSessions(options =>
{
     options.Cookie.Name = ".AppX";
});
```

```
app.UseSessions();
```